# mysql find three consecutive rows with the same value

Tags: mysql

I have read a few similar questions on counting consecutive rows, but none of them gave me a clear answer. I hope someone could give me some help with my problem. I have the following table data:

```
ID       TEST_VALUES
 1       A
 2       B
 3       C
 4       C
 5       C
 6       C
 7       A
 8       D
 9       D
 10      D
 11      B
 12      C
 13      C
 14      C
 15      C
```

now I want to find three consecutive rows with the same value within the ID range is 1 to 10,such as when the ID range is 1 to 10,there has the 'C' continuous appear more than three times.
(note: this question has nothing to do with ID,The column ID is only the condition for my query,such as where ID > 1 and ID < 10)

Comment: Not quite a job for SQL. SQL works with sets and, by its definition, a set is [a collection of items whose order is irrelevant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)#Describing_sets). It can probably be done in MySQL using variables. Ugly.

Comment: A pure SQL solution exists (i.e. one that does not transform the query into a `for` loop by the presence of variables, assignments and incrementation) but it works only if there aren't any gaps in the values of the `ID` column.

Comment: @axiac, this can be done in pure SQL with several LEFT JOINs, with no need for the IDs to be sequential. It's a bit tricky so I can't write it at the moment but when I have some time I'll post the solution. I can tell you in advance that like my first solution, it will return a single row, but it will also return the matching IDs, each in a separate column, which is hopefully good enough to satisfy the OP.

Comment: @kmoser I guess *"several"* means one less than the number of consecutive rows that are required to have the same value in the `TEST_VALUES` column. The solution I was referring to uses only one `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this one,

```
SELECT TEST_VALUES, MAX(cnt) AS maxCount
FROM (
  SELECT TEST_VALUES, ID, COUNT(grp) AS cnt
  FROM (
    SELECT ID, TEST_VALUES, rn - rnByVal AS grp
    FROM (
      SELECT ID, TEST_VALUES,
           @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn,
           @rnByVal := IF (@val = TEST_VALUES,
                          IF (@val := TEST_VALUES, @rnByVal + 1, @rnByVal + 1),
                          IF (@val := TEST_VALUES, 1, 1)) AS rnByVal
      FROM mytable
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @rnByVal := 0, @val := '') AS vars
      ORDER BY ID) AS t 
    ) AS s
  GROUP BY TEST_VALUES, grp ) AS u
GROUP BY TEST_VALUES
```

It will be return maximum count for occurring consecutive rows with the same value(more then 1).

Comment: Thanks for your answer,the answer is close to what I want！

Comment: Ok @bfther. If its useful means please vote/accept my answer.

Comment: The `@rnByVal` assignment  has conditions with duplicated and always true instructions that can be simplified like this :  `@val := TEST_VALUES, @rnByVal := IF (@val = TEST_VALUES, @rnByVal + 1, 1) AS rnByVal`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(`TEST_VALUES` ORDER BY `id` ASC) AS g
FROM
    `tbl`
WHERE
    `ID` >=1 AND `ID` <= 10
HAVING
    g LIKE '%C,C,C,C%'
```

Ordering the `GROUP_CONCAT()` by `id` ensures the results are sequential. The `HAVING` clause extracts only those rows which contain at least four sequential instances of C.

Comment: I almost upvoted this answer then I realized that, because of the lack of a `GROUP BY` clause, it generates only one row that contains all values of the `TEST_VALUE` column joined with comma.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: @axiac, that is exactly what the OP asked for: it returns a single row indicating whether there are at least 4 consecutive "C"s in the records being analyzed. I suppose I should have added ``WHERE ID >=1 AND id <= 10``, but otherwise it fulfills the requirement.

Comment: @bfther, does this do what you want? If so, please upvote it. If not, please describe where it falls short.

Comment: The question reads *"now I want to find three consecutive rows with the same value ..."* -- I understand the request is to find **the rows** and not just if they exists.

Comment: The answer posted by the OP also returns only values from the `TEST_VALUES` column, without any reference to the `ID` column. This approach turns this into a valid answer. I'd like to retract my down vote but, unfortunately, [so] does not allow retracting a down vote until the answer is edited.

Comment: @axiac, I've edited my answer to add the ``WHERE`` clause. Feel free to retract your downvote, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I also think of a solution,hoping to help others

```
SELECT 
TEST_VALUES 
FROM(
    SELECT
    m.TEST_VALUES AS TEST_VALUES,
    IF(@b = m.TEST_VALUES, @a := @a +1, @a := 0) AS countNUM,
    @b := m.TEST_VALUES
    FROM tableName m
    JOIN (
      SELECT 
      @a := 0
    ) AS t
) AS TEMP
WHERE countNUM >= 2
GROUP BY TEST_VALUES
```

Answer (score 1):

Convoluted, but tested and working:

```
    SELECT t1.ID AS t1_id, t1.TEST_VALUES AS t1_values,
(SELECT ID FROM test WHERE test.ID > t1.ID LIMIT 1 ) AS t2_id, (SELECT TEST_VALUES FROM test WHERE test.ID > t1.ID LIMIT 1 ) AS t2_values,
(SELECT ID FROM test WHERE test.ID > (SELECT ID FROM test WHERE test.ID > t1.ID LIMIT 1 ) LIMIT 1 ) AS t3_id, (SELECT TEST_VALUES FROM test WHERE test.ID > (SELECT ID FROM test WHERE test.ID > t1.ID LIMIT 1 ) LIMIT 1 ) AS t3_values,
(SELECT ID FROM test WHERE test.ID > (SELECT ID FROM test WHERE test.ID > (SELECT ID FROM test WHERE test.ID > t1.ID LIMIT 1 ) LIMIT 1 ) LIMIT 1 ) AS t4_id, (SELECT TEST_VALUES FROM test WHERE test.ID > (SELECT ID FROM test WHERE test.ID > (SELECT ID FROM test WHERE test.ID > t1.ID LIMIT 1 ) LIMIT 1 ) LIMIT 1 ) AS t4_values
FROM test AS t1
HAVING (
    ID BETWEEN 1 AND 10 AND t2_id BETWEEN 1 AND 10 AND t3_id BETWEEN 1 AND 10 AND t4_id BETWEEN 1 AND 10
        AND
t1_values = t2_values AND t2_values = t3_values AND t3_values = t4_values
)
```

Gives these results:

```
+-------+-----------+-------+-----------+-------+-----------+-------+-----------+
| t1_id | t1_values | t2_id | t2_values | t3_id | t3_values | t4_id | t4_values |
+-------+-----------+-------+-----------+-------+-----------+-------+-----------+
|     3 | C         |     4 | C         |     5 | C         |     6 | C         |
+-------+-----------+-------+-----------+-------+-----------+-------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```